# Is it possible to access s3 endpoint from an application without using access key or IAM role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to upload file in s3 endpoint from an application without using access key or IAM role?

Answer (score 1):

This type of use case is typically solved [using pre-signed S3 URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

This does require someone/something with AWS credentials (user/role) to generate the a URL with temporary credentials that can be given to someone else and gives them permissions to upload a file.

A typically workflow would be

1. a user makes a request to an API you control for permission to upload a file.
2. the API (who has an IAM role with S3 access to the bucket) generates a presigned URL that contains temp credentials that expire after a configurable time which and returns the URL to the user.
3. The user can then use that URL to upload a file

This allows you to enable your users/clients to upload files to s3 without having to worry about giving them roles or managing AWS credentials for them.

Comment: API that will generate need to have  the access key of s3 bucket  that to need to store the access key.We are using eks cluster to deploy our application and worker node without any IAM role attached with it so we have to  pass the s3 access key in the application.

Comment: can use 'Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referer' for referer can we use https urls

Comment: @KhushbooKumari EKS supports IAM roles for pods. Don't try to make up your own way to avoid doing this correctly. 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if I attached the IAM role to eks worker node than also it's works ?